# Splitting GraphQL mutations and queries into multiple schema files

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql

I am using Spring Boot and Netflix's DGS library for GraphQL on the backend. Our app has multiple modules (multi-gradle project) and each module is responsible for one thing. Therefore, I wanted to split GQL schema into multiple files based on the business logic of that module (let's say we have packages like `cars, people, animals` and parent module `app`, which contains the main SpringBootApp class), so I want only mutations and queries for one particular package on the path and not others. (I don't want to see Mutations for `cars` in the `animal` package)

Problem is that I cannot have multiple definitions of the `Mutation` type in the project, so I tried to put `extend type Mutation`, but this fails when I run my tests because they don't know the parent since the only schema for cars is copied and not the parent.

I also tried to create some Gradle task, that would copy the schema and remove the `extend` keyword from the file, which would work, but it's not the best solution.

Another option would be perhaps to create a new type for mutations like `UseMutation`, `CarMutation`, but not sure if that is the correct approach.

Do you have any other ideas, how to work and deal with this schema separation? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably have a folder entitled `schema` , where all your schema definitions reside.

You may have, for example in `car.js`:

```
extend type Mutation{
 someRandomMutation : String !
}

extend type Query{
 someRandomQuery : Int!
}
```

Then , in your `index.js` you have to basically define the type `Mutation` and `Query` for all these pieces that extend them in the first place:

```
import car from './car'
   import people from './people'

    const linkSchema=gql`
        scalar Date    
        scalar Upload
        
        type Query{
            _:Boolean
        }
    
        type Mutation{
            _:Boolean
        }
    
        type Subscription{
            _:Boolean
        }
    `
    export default [car , people , linkSchema]
```

Then, in the `index.js` of your server (or wherever you initialize Apollo Server):

```
import typeDefs from './schema'

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    ....
  });
```